# Laravel validation required rule not working

Tags: validation, laravel, requiredfieldvalidator

I need to add required rule if one field is available. Also need to check if it is an integer and 10 digit. So I added the rule like below.

```
'id_number' => 'sometimes|required|digits:10|integer'
```

Validations works only when the field is available. But here required rule is not working. It directly shows `integer` error even if the field is empty.

I use Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured it!

You need to change the order of required rule to last. It works when I add rule like this,

```
'id_number' => 'sometimes|digits:10|integer|required'
```

Comment: Did you figure out why this is happening? I have the same problem, but the official documentation says that it should be `sometimes|required`?

Comment: @DmitryTorba In Laravel validation, normally all rules will be validated. My problem was, I was trying to add these error messages to a string instead of array. So all my error messages were being overwritten.