# Laravel sometimes and require rule unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-request

I working on Laravel application. In `UserRequest` I am validating the input. The following rule:

```
'name' => 'sometimes|required|string|min:2|max:50'
```

fails if user name is not present although there is `sometimes` keyword present. The following request works fine though:

```
'name' => 'sometimes|string|min:2|max:50'
```

I am not the first one to experience this problem (see [Laravel validation required rule not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393134/laravel-validation-required-rule-not-working)).

However, documentation says that I should use the first option:

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
]);
```

> In the example above, the email field will only be validated if it is present in the $data array.

(https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation)

Does some know if that something I am doing wrong or a bug that needs to be reported?

Comment: It's just an order of operations problem. In the 5.1 core there's an internal issue with an explode and glue. I'll save you the boring basics but `required` needs to be the last attribute when `sometimes` is present, which coincidentally needs to be the `first` attribute.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy but changing it did not help